# How to handle the multiple timeouts in alert messages

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with handling the multiple timeouts in displaying the alert messages. In my app i get several alert messages when create a task, play the task, pause the task and delete a task. I set the timeout for all alerts as 5000 using $timeout().

This is the code for creating a task::

```
$scope.create = function () {
        console.log('Taskkkkkkkkkk Title create function is called : ');
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.tasks[i].title === this.title) {
                $scope.duplicateTitle = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        var task = new Tasks({
            'title': this.title,
            'description': this.description,
            'duration': 0,
            'lastStart': '',
            'archive': false,
            'active': true
        });

        console.log('Taskkkkkkkkkk Title : ' + task.title);
        if (task.title) {
            task.$save(function (response) {
                $scope.alerts.push({
                    type: 'success',
                    msg: 'Task have been Added!!' + '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" ng-click="closeAlert()">&times;</button>'
                });

                $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
                    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
                };

                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.alerts.splice($scope.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
                }, 5000);

                $scope.tasks.unshift(response);
                //$scope.tasks = Tasks.query();
                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.description = '';
                $state.go('listTasks');
            }, function (errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        } else {
            var message = 'Title cannot be blank';
            $scope.error = message;
        }
    };
```

But When i click the multiple tasks within 5sec, the last task alert message will de disappearing. But not the first one, means it is folling the stack order i.e., FIFO principle. I am writing the alert messages in the controllers.

I want the tasks to be disappeared in the order which they are arised. Any suggestions will be more helpful to me.

Comment: Please give us some code to reproduce your problem, we can guess among many possible bugs in your code but SO isn't a guessing game.

Comment: I added the code for creating a task. For other functions also i use the same timeouts functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There in the timeout i just added the index value for the splice function.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
}, 5000);
```

its working fine now...